# How to fix the issue mail merge issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: erro message preview]

I am trying to create an approval flow using sheet mail merge with approval buttons in the mail . Mail could generate when the user submits the HTML form.
Below script is not working I have attached the script with sample sheet.

I am not able to identify the exact issue, please help me to fix or identify

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sS8_GQ3EMcsXCtj_j8LKg4jywKMu_8symTAFbIkGyh4/edit?usp=sharing)

```js
var REQUESTS_STATE_COLUMN = 32;
var STATE_APPROVERS_EMAILED = "EMAILED_Response Pending";
var STATE_APPROVED = "Approved";
var STATE_DENIED = "Rejected";


function sendEmail(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:AH2");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var email = e.namedValues["Email Address"];
    var emailAddress = rowData[30];
    var submiterEmail = rowData[1];
    var ProjectName = rowData[2];
    var SrDesign = "Sr. Design Architect Services";
    var PerHourRate = rowData[6];    
    var NumberOfHours = rowData[7];
    var TotalRate = rowData[8];
    var Contact  = "Contact Centre Expert";
    var PerHourRate2 = rowData[10];
    var NumberOfHours2 = rowData[11];
    var NTotalRate2 = rowData[12];
    var NJrDesign = "Jr. Design Architect";
    var PerHourRate3 = rowData[14];
    var NumberOfHours3 = rowData[15];
    var TotalRate3 = rowData[16];
    var Outsourced = "Outsourced Technical Support Resource";
    var PerHourRate4 = rowData[18];
    var NumberOfHours4 = rowData[19];
    var TotalRate4 = rowData[20];
    var Supplier = "Supplier Management";
    var PerHourRate5 = rowData[22];
    var NumberOfHours5 = rowData[23];
    var TotalRate5 = rowData[24];
    var Project = "Project Management & Execution";
    var PerHourRate6 = rowData[26];
    var NumberOfHours6 = rowData[27];
    var TotalRate6 = rowData[28];
    var UserAccount = rowData[28];
    var GrandTotalRate = rowData[29];
    var seq = e.values[1];
    var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1i5x0oqpCDgOZO2Nbly4SpNkWpLbTXJhT6pPOfQ7NuEc').getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var cellval = range.getCell(row,1).getValue();


  var options = '?approval=%APPROVE%&reply=%EMAIL%'
           .replace("%EMAIL%",e.namedValues["User Email Address"])         
  var approve = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Approved")+'&row='+data+'&cellval='+cellval; 
  var reject = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Rejected")+'&row='+data+'&cellval='+cellval;

 var subject = 'Technology Charges for '+ProjectName+''; 
var html = '<p style="font-family:Verdana; fontsize=9px">Hello Recipient,<br/><br/><br/><br/>Referance No: '+cellval+'<br/><a href='+ approve +'> <b>approve </b></a><a href='+ reject +'> <b>Reject</b></a><br/>'
MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: html,
  });

   //Add a state in the form spreadsheet with APPROVERS_EMAILED state  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, REQUESTS_STATE_COLUMN+1).setValue(STATE_APPROVERS_EMAILED);

}
}

function doGet(e){
  var answer = (e.parameter.approval === 'Approved') ? 'Yes -Approved!' : 'No-Rejected '; 
  var cellval = e.parameter.cellval;
  var email = e.parameter.reply;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1i5x0oqpCDgOZO2Nbly4SpNkWpLbTXJhT6pPOfQ7NuEc").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data[0];
  var approvalCol = headers.indexOf("Approval") + 1;
  if (0 === approvalCol) throw new Error ("Must add Approval column.");

  // Record approval or rejection in spreadsheet
  var row = ArrayLib.indexOf(data, 0, cellval);
  if (row < 0) throw new Error ("Request not available.");  // Throw error if request was not found
  sheet.getRange(row+1, approvalCol).setValue(e.parameter.approval);

  // Display response to approver
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.createHTML('<h2>Thank you..! Your response has been recorded'+' saying: '+ answer + '</h2>'))
  return app
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getCell` requires integer value for row and column but instead you are passing the entire row (*rowData*). You need to replace the line 45 to the below line.

```
var cellval = dataRange.getCell(i+1, 1).getValue()
```

Comment: Thanks, Riz, able to send the email, Help me to fix the  approval buttons  issue (It's redirecting to http://null/?approval=Approved&reply=kiran.shetty@teamcomputers.com&row=IMACD-00001,Mon)
var approve = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Approved")+'&row='+data+'&cellval='+cellval; 
  var reject = url+options.replace("%APPROVE%","Rejected")+'&row='+data+'&cellval='+cellval;

Comment: `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` will return null if you haven't published the script not even once

Comment: Riz.....Error 
Execution failed: ReferenceError: "ArrayLib" is not defined. (line 83, file "Code")

Comment: yes, the array `ArrayLib` is not defined in your code

Comment: Thanks, added the "In  Library"
https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library
Can you please review my code, not able to trigger the mail on from submit

Comment: @KiiranShetty it's better to post a new question for the new error